# AngularJS style is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have just started with angular ,and I am facing issue with this ,I followed most of the related answers but they does'nt seems to work

```
  <section id="contactForm" ng-app="duty">
    <form method="post" ng-controller="submitagain" ng-submit="submitForm()" >
    <h2 class="ft-heading text-upper">DUTY SLIP</h2>


    <label> <b>R.A. No.</b> <span class="required small"></span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required ng-model="form.rnum" name="name" value="" />

            <div class="col-md-3" >
              <div ng-style="alpha" class="loader"></div> //problem here
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </section>
```

And this is my angular code

```
 var app=angular.module("duty",[]);
    app.controller('submitagain', function ($scope,$http){
      var formData = {
          name: "default",
          email: "default",
          textareacontent: "default",
          gender: "default",
          member: false
      };
      $scope.alpha={
      "display":"none"  }

    $scope.submitForm = function() {

$http({

              url: "dutyenquiry.php",
              data: $scope.form,
              method: 'POST',
              dataType:'html',
              headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}

          }).then(function (response){

            $scope.myObj={
              "display" : "none",
            }
            //$('.form-control').val("");
    var output=JSON.stringify(response);
        console.log(response);


          },function (error){

       });
      }

      });
```

I am trying to change the visibility of the loader but it is not working ,I don't know why.I want to start the loader when the form is submitted and remove it when I get a reply from server.
Any help ??

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ng-show to set visibility of your loader

```
<div ng-show="displayLoader" class="loader"></div>
```

and inside your submit form function

```
     $scope.submitForm = function () {
        $scope.displayLoader = true;
        $http({
            url: "dutyenquiry.php",
            data: $scope.form,
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' }
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.displayLoader = false;
            var output = JSON.stringify(response);
            console.log(response);
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.displayLoader = false;
        });
    }
```

but if you want to use ng-style for this purpose you can try following

```
    $scope.submitForm = function () {
        $scope.alpha = { 'display': 'inline' }; //default value of display
        $http({
            url: "dutyenquiry.php",
            data: $scope.form,
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' }
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.alpha = { 'display': 'none' };
            var output = JSON.stringify(response);
            console.log(response);
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.alpha = { 'display': 'none' };
        });
    }
```